# How do i check the thunderbolt port?

Tags: drivers, acer-aspire, thunderbolt, intel

I have an acer aspire 7 A715-51G. On the spec sheet it says it has thunderbolt 4 and also on the port it has the small logo. But i can't see any drivers for thunderbolt nor can i see it in the intel thunderbolt controller(which i installed manually)

So is there some other way to verify that there is thuderbolt on the laptop?
Should there be some drivers in device manager or it works without it?
Also can i charge using the thunderbolt port?